# what is "BasicDream" in android ICS?

Tags: android

I read the Launcher source code which version is ICS. There is a `RocketLauncher` class which extends `BasicDream`. what is `BasicDream`? what can `BasicDream` do? I can find this line `import android.support.v13.dreams.BasicDream;`, but I can't find any information about it on Internet. Please give me some information to understand it. Thanks!

Update: I found those code in launcher manifest.xml
`<activity android:name="com.android.launcher2.RocketLauncher"
            android:label="@string/dream_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DREAM" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>`

There is a new category `android.intent.category.DREAM`, what is it used to do? That RocketLauncher is an `Activity`?

Comment: I just figured this is another one of Google's jokes

Comment: If it were a joke, there would be an ElectricSheep implementation, non?

Comment: it seems to have an API too : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/dreams/BasicDream.html#BasicDream%28%29 . i'm still not sure what it is . some say it's a screensaver , but i never saw a screensaver . plus it's in the support library , so what gives?

Answer (score 2):

It is probably a private library that is enclosed in the APK but not released with the source code. They did the same thing with their market application.

There is only one way to see it and that is to decompile an APK. But this assumes that you have rooted an ICS phone. Which is actually very possible with the emulator.. hmm *ponder*

Comment: Dreams are part of the support library v13 public API.

Answer (score 2):

when you complete to compile android source, you will acquire "android-support-v13.jar" in "out/host/linux-x86/sdk/android-sdk_eng.wj_linux-x86/extras/android/support/v13" . now ,you can make this jar & android.jar to one jar, replace the android.jar in platforms.

there is "readme.txt" that describe this class in "out/host/linux-x86/sdk/android-sdk_eng.wj_linux-x86/extras/android/support".

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, Dream is some sort of screensaver in ICS.

You can find source of `BasicDream` in the Android sources in `frameworks/support/v13/java/android/support/v13/dreams` or online at the [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v13/dreams/BasicDream.java).

Answer (score 0):

`android-support-v13` is an Android compatibility library. 
The description for the same is : "Support classes to ease implementation of Dreams in a backwards compatible fashion."

`BasicDream` is a simple Dream implementation that can be sub classed to write your own Dreams. It takes care of a number of housekeeping tasks that most **screensavers** will want.

Answer (score 0):

You can download `frameworks/support/` here [MIPS / frameworks-support](https://github.com/MIPS/frameworks-support)