# android.support.v13.dreams.BasicDream cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-support-library, libs

I'm trying to work on extending BasicDream which exists in package: **android.support.v13.dreams**. I have tried downloading all most all android version (just trying luck to get it working) but I'm unable to import it. i.e. On
   `import android.support.v13.dreams.BasicDream;` statement I'm getting an error:
**The import xxxxxx... cannot be resolved**.

I tried copying my *sdk/extras/libs/../android-support-v13.jar* in my libs folder and added to build path but found this package does not show **dreams**. While typing import statement I'm able to see v13 i.e. I can write import **android.support.v13.app.*;** but it does not have dreams/basicdream.

Tried google and do found the source code of this class but no idea why my jar file does not have these classes or how to use it. Please suggest what am I missing here.

**Update**: Finally I figured out that **BasicDream** was part of **Android Support Library version 13** Link: [BasicDream source code](http://goo.gl/UaHeu)shipped with android **4.1.2** however latest **Android Support Library version 13** does not have Basic Dream.[support library v13 class list](http://goo.gl/AbwK0)

As I'm working on some native functionality, I downloaded BasicDream source code from the link mentioned above and included in same folder where I have my other source files. Updated the package to my application package

Comment: Have you updated to the latest version of the library?

Comment: yes.. Everything in Android SDK manager is latest.

Comment: @Rohit Kandhal probably there is not such class because it's not exist at all in support package and your import is wrong? [V13 Classes Lits](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/package-summary.html)

Comment: @Evos You are right that latest support package does not have dream but have a look to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920735/what-is-basicdream-in-android-ics and infact I found source code for that too

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/support/v13/dreams/BasicDream.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case probably the best way to get it is to check code of this class on [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v13/dreams/BasicDream.java) and manually resolve (copy) all dependencies. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks but I know this. Will wait for someone who could come up with other solution..

Comment: Finally downloaded the above file and included in my project. Changed namespace to my project namespace from android.support.v13.dreams